# Module Catchment area (Parallel) missing from QGIS processing?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have qgis 2.4.0 chugiak and have installed processing but in the box of tools not exist the module catchment area (parallel), how to install this module?

Comment: Are you referring to the SAGA algorithm? http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/terrain_analysis_hydrology/catchmentarea.html

Comment: Assuming it is the SAGA algorithm as @underdark mentioned, try checking if it is enabled (_Processing_ > _Options and configuration_ > _Providers_ > _SAGA_)